# How to find ViewModels in project?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This question might sound so basic to MVVM experts but I'm trying to understand how should I know when I need to create ViewModel and how many ... OK I have learned that ViewModel is the glue between View (UI) and Model (Data) but sometimes I see an applications has 2 UIs only and one Model but then there are 5 ViewModels involved in it.

In fact, all I need to understand is what phenomenon in a project should be represented by a ViewModel?

Let's say we have a phone book app. So I'm assuming Contacts need a UI e.g. search. display, edit and delete do tell me how many UIs I need. Also,

```
{
 string firstName,
 string lastName,
 string phone,
 bool isCompany
}
```

can be a structure for the Model.

Now, when it gets to ViewModel how many ViewModels are we dealing with? and how do you recognize them?

I hope this is clear.

Comment: I don't think there's a hard and fast rule -- just follow good OO design principles like DRY, single responsibility, etc.

Comment: DRY: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: so would it be OK if I choose 1)AddViewModel 2)DeleteViewModel 3)EditViewModel 4)DispalyViewModel and maybe an abstract class as ModelViewBase so those will be derived from it? and I might need a class as RelayCommand as Josh has described in his article ...!

Comment: No, think of the ViewModel like a table in a database - it stores your data for the View, but it does so in a way that is independent of the underlying data store. Then, when the View is ready to update the data store (e.g. add, update or delete the record(s)), a command is called and the ViewModel then updates the Model (typically a database, but doesn't have to be). Also, you would likely want to have a methods/commands in your ViewModel like `Update(int contactID)`, `Delete(int contactID)` and `Add(Contact contact)`.

Comment: No I'm getting something Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given your example, I'd arrange the project like this:

- Contacts [Project]

  - Views [Folder]

    - MainWindow.xaml *(Grid with all contacts displayed & toolbar to add/edit/delete records)*
    - CustomerInfo.xaml *(Form with fields for each property of the Customer object)*
  - ViewModels [Folder]

    - MainWindowViewModel.cs *(ViewModel for MainWindow)*
    - CustomerInfoViewModel.cs *(ViewModel for CustomerInfo)*
  - Models

    - Customer.cs

One thing to note is that I'd have the CustomerInfo screen responsible for handling the logic to add a new customer & edit an existing one. There's no sense in having essentially a duplicate form - just populate the values of each field on initialization when the user is editing an existing customer.

Also, the delete button on the grid could call execute command to delete the selected user; this could also be done from the CustomerInfo screen as well (to delete the current customer).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using MVC long, however, in my shop the ViewModel is how we structure our data that we want to pass to the Views and one of the ways that helped me to understand it is that it can be used to combine two or more models to use in a specific view.

Models
Setup the properties you want your object to have, in this example Contact returns a type "Person" and ContactAddress returns a type "Address" (I used different data types because I thought it made a more clear example, I hope I didn't confuse anything):

```
public class Models
{

public Person Contact
{
    // properties of first Model
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
}


public Address ContactAddress 
{
    // properties of second Model
    string Address1;
    string Address2;
    string City;
    string State;
    string Zip;
}
}// EndModels
```

ViewModel
We know our end view is going to require Contact data as well as their ContactAddress data. We can use the ViewModel as a way to hold both sets of data and pass it to our View.

```
public class ContactVM
{
   // properties of the ViewModel, to hold data for each Model we need to pass to the view 
   public Person Contacts {get; set;}
   public Address ContactAddresses {get;set;} 

   // Constructor
   public ContactVM()
   {
        Contacts = new Person();
        ContactAddresses = new Address();
   }
}
```

Controller
The controller is going to call the ViewModel and then make calls for each of the ViewModel
properties to populate them with the correct data. There are many ways this can be done, but I am excluding it for ease of example.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // create an instance of the ViewModel
    ContactVM contacts = new ContactVM();

    // make calls to populate your ViewModel properties with the correct data
    contacts.Contacts = //call to populate your Contact data here
    contacts.ContactAddresses = //call to populate your Address data here

    // pass the ViewModel to the View for use
    return View(contacts);
}
```